# sequence points in java

Tags: java, sequence-points

Is there a guaranteed sequence of execution of the following java code:

```
int i = getA() + getB();
```

Is `getA()` always executed before `getB()`, as any average person would expect?

Comment: Note, Java guarantees that the method are called in order, however the CPU may re-order the loads if it has no effect on the outcome.  For example if B is in cache but A is not, it won't wait for A to finish before starting to load B but it will ensure it has no impact on the result.

Comment: Now that's interesting. The two functions do not have any classic sideffects on each other. It's just that `getA()` may take some time to execute while `getB()` is almost a no-op. I want to make sure that the second one returns as soon as the first one returns, so the ordering is important. I could rewrite it of course.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it is. From the JLS, section 15.7:

> The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order, namely, from left to right.
>
> It is recommended that code not rely crucially on this specification. Code is usually clearer when each expression contains at most one side effect, as its outermost operation, and when code does not depend on exactly which exception arises as a consequence of the left-to-right evaluation of expressions.
>
> ...
>
> The left-hand operand of a binary operator appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the right-hand operand is evaluated.

and also:

> The Java programming language also guarantees that every operand of an operator (except the conditional operators &&, ||, and ? :) appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the operation itself is performed.