# why does the same code work differently in java?

Tags: java, c

I wrote following codes in java and C. But output of those programs are different.
Java application gave 21 and C application gave 22 (I use GCC compiler).

Can you describe this ?

Here is the JAVA code.

```
class test
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int a =5;
        int b = (++a) + (++a) + (++a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }

}
```

Here is the C code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
int a =5;
int b = (++a) + (++a) + (++a);
printf("%d \n",b);
}
```

Comment: If it isn't obvious, you should never, NEVER write code like this in programs that don't fall into "Hello world" type of programs.

Comment: @darioo never never = always. It's like `!!a`.

Comment: @Radek: english language works a bit differently

Comment: You should learn to accept answers btw :)

Answer (score 34):

```
int b = (++a) + (++a) + (++a);
```

This is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in C, which means it can output 21, 22, 42, it can crash or do whatever else it wants to. This is UB because the value of a scalar object is changed more than once within the same expression without intervening [sequence points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point)

The behavior is defined in Java because it has more sequence points. [Here's an explanatory link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352954/sequence-points-in-java)

Comment: Is it defined behaviour in Java?

Comment: @Janaka because there is no way to know in which order the commands should be executed.
@Armen I believe that it is actually defined that all the expressions should be executed but just the order is undefined.

Comment: @Armen It is defined see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352954/sequence-points-in-java

Comment: I believe that the technical term is "nasal demons" - http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nasal+demons

Answer (score 3):

In Java evaluation is [left to right](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html), so the result is consistent. 6 + 7 + 8 == 21