# Turbo C++ (not visual)(Postfix and prefix operators)

Tags: c++, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

When I run this program I get output as 2

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main(){
    clrscr();
    int a = 10;
    int c = a-- - --a;
    cout<<c;
    getch();
}
```

... but when I just modify it to

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main(){
    clrscr();
    int a = 10,c;
    c = a-- - --a;
    cout<<c;
    getch();
}
```

... I get output 0. WHY? In java both the of them gave output as 2. Whats wrong with C++? 
Explain :(

Comment: Nothing is wrong with C++ but everything is wrong with your code. Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points/4176333#4176333

Comment: @KingsIndian pretty sure you mean daily.

Comment: haha...On a serious note: OP might want to [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352954/sequence-points-in-java) for why it's not an issue in Java.

Comment: Besides, the only correct signatures for main are `int main(int, char**)` and `int main()`. DON'T NEVER WRITE `void main()`, it just hurts our eyes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could anyone explain these undefined behaviors (i = i++ + ++i , i = i++, etc...)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc)

Comment: Please do not tag it as C++, since Turbo C++ is not C++

Comment: @PlasmaHH: In fact, this is purely a standard C++ question. It has nothing to do with the specific compiler, though OP did not know it initially.

Comment: @Gorpik: all code he posted so far is quite far away from standard c++

Comment: @PlasmaHH: `clrscr()` is very accessory here. The interesing part of the code is standard C++; it does not work as OP expected, but once again the reason can be found in the standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing wrong with C++, but there's something wrong in how you're using it.

The expression `a-- - --a` has undefined behavior in C++, and anything can happen.

The cleanest solution is to not write code like that (I wouldn't do it even if it were legal).

Comment: ... but its a part of my school syllabus and the book we are following has some parts dedicated to this prefix and postfix stuff. What to do?

Comment: @SouradeepNanda fight the system!

Comment: This has nothing to do with the operators in themselves, it's a matter of expression evaluation (that is: don't use two or more of them in the same expression, because you don't know how the expression will be evaluated).

Comment: Prefix and postfix operators are useful, but you should only use them one at a time.

Comment: Yeah, I removed the java tag. I wish I could vote it up but it requires 15 reputation. Thanks anyways :D

Comment: @SouradeepNanda: You cannot upvote, but you can select the answer as correct, if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate a bit on Luchian's answer. In C++, the order in which sub-expressions are evaluated inside an expression is not specified. This means that in the following expression:

```
int c = a-- - --a;
```

there are two equally valid evaluation orders.

1. Evaluate `a--` first (returns `10`), then `--a` (returns `8`), then
   substract (returns `2`).
2. Evaluate `--a` first (returns `9`), then
   `a--` (returns `9`), then substract (returns `0`).

This is meant to improve optimisation oportunities for compilers. Naturally, this means that in C++ it is a mistake to use expressions that depend on evaluation order, because there is no way to know which order the compiler will select. The trade-off between efficiency and error avoidance is different in C++ and in Java.